# Is it possible to get the element of certain range of index... is it possible?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I am using a 2D Array and i would like to get the element of certain range of index... is it possible?

Below is my 2D Array:

```
var entryCoordinate: [[Float]] = [[130.6,61.0],[167.5,61.0],[204.5,61.0],[243.6,61.0],[281.16,61.0],[315.3,61.0]]
```

For Example, i would like to get the element from row index 0 to 4.

Comment: let slice = entryCoordinate[0...4]

Comment: is it can do it like this without a loop?

Comment: where's the loop?

Comment: @BlU3_5KY can you make question more clear?